# linq collection of objects

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have this piece of code that works:

```
        var mealsAndSchoolsPerformance = new List<MealsAndSchoolPerformanceUI>();

        foreach (SchoolModel sc in schoolData.Where(s => s.IsHidden == false))
        {
            var mealAndSchoolP = new MealsAndSchoolPerformanceUI
            {
                Id = sc.Id,
                SchoolName = sc.SchoolName,
                Week = DateExtensions.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(startDate, true),
                TotalFoodSpent = foodSpend.ContainsKey(sc.Id) ? foodSpend[sc.Id] : 0,
                TotalHours = totalHours.ContainsKey(sc.Id) ? totalHours[sc.Id]: 0,
                MealsKs1 = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.KeyStage1).Sum(s => s.MealNo), 
                MealsKs2 = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.KeyStage2).Sum(s => s.MealNo), 
                MealsNursery = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.Nursery).Sum(s => s.MealNo), 
                MealsStaff = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.Adult).Sum(s => s.MealNo),
                MealsSenior = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.Senior).Sum(s => s.MealNo),
                TotalSales = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Sum(m => m.TotalPrice),
                TotalInvoicePrice = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Sum(m => m.TotalInvoicePrice),
                Region = sc.SchoolLead?.AddressRegion ?? " ",
                SchoolGroup = sc.SchoolGroups.FirstOrDefault()?.GroupName ?? "",
                Manager = sc.ManagerUser?.FullName ?? "",
                ServiceStarted = sc.ServiceStarted,
                RollNoNursery = sc.RollNoNursery ?? 0,
                RollNoSchool = sc.RollNoSchool ?? 0,
                ServingDays = MealBL.MealServingDays(sc.Id, startDate, startDate.AddDays(6))
            };
            mealsAndSchoolsPerformance.Add(mealAndSchoolP);
        }
```

question is: is there any way of initialising the list and each object at the same time in order to improve performance? something like

var mealsAndSchoolsPerformance = new List();

Comment: You know `Where` so I guess you also know `Select`.

Comment: this object gets the data from several objects, so I'm having issues at combining them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to initialize a list and multiple objects "at the same time". Linq can make your code shorter but under the hood it will `foreach` over the data just the same.

But you can improve performance: you're executing the `meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id)` part multiple times, while you could do this once and hang on to the result:

```
foreach (SchoolModel sc in schoolData.Where(s => s.IsHidden == false))
{
    var schoolMeals = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).ToArray();
    ...
    TotalSales = schoolMeals.Sum(m => m.TotalPrice),
    TotalInvoicePrice = schoolMeals.Sum(m => m.TotalInvoicePrice),
```

Furthermore you're running similar `InvoiceMealType` queries over the same data, where you could do this in a single pass:

```
foreach (SchoolModel sc in schoolData.Where(s => s.IsHidden == false))
{
    var schoolMeals = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id);
    var byInvoiceMealType = schoolMeals.ToLookup(m => m.InvoiceMealType);
    ...
    MealsKs1 = byInvoiceMealType[InvoiceMealType.KeyStage1].Sum(s => s.MealNo),
```

Perhaps this was not the answer you were hoping to get - and how much performance is gained depends on the source and amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/parallel-linq-plinq) from [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) to initialize objects on multiple threads at once, giving you performance boost on multi-core processors. This assumes that data sources used in object initialization, such as `foodSpend` and `meals`, are thread-safe for reading and enumeration (I cannot tell if it is the case without knowing types of these objects, but `Dictionary<T>`, `List<T>` and arrays are safe to be used this way, for other types you will have to check thread safety yourself).

```
var mealsAndSchoolsPerformance = schoolData
    .Where(s => s.IsHidden == false)
    .AsParallel()//This causes that following query will run on multiple threads
    .Select(sc => new MealsAndSchoolPerformanceUI
        {
            Id = sc.Id,
            SchoolName = sc.SchoolName,
            Week = DateExtensions.GetIso8601WeekOfYear(startDate, true),
            TotalFoodSpent = foodSpend.ContainsKey(sc.Id) ? foodSpend[sc.Id] : 0,
            TotalHours = totalHours.ContainsKey(sc.Id) ? totalHours[sc.Id]: 0,
            MealsKs1 = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.KeyStage1).Sum(s => s.MealNo), 
            MealsKs2 = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.KeyStage2).Sum(s => s.MealNo), 
            MealsNursery = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.Nursery).Sum(s => s.MealNo), 
            MealsStaff = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.Adult).Sum(s => s.MealNo),
            MealsSenior = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Where(m => m.InvoiceMealType == InvoiceMealType.Senior).Sum(s => s.MealNo),
            TotalSales = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Sum(m => m.TotalPrice),
            TotalInvoicePrice = meals.Where(m => m.SchoolId == sc.Id).Sum(m => m.TotalInvoicePrice),
            Region = sc.SchoolLead?.AddressRegion ?? " ",
            SchoolGroup = sc.SchoolGroups.FirstOrDefault()?.GroupName ?? "",
            Manager = sc.ManagerUser?.FullName ?? "",
            ServiceStarted = sc.ServiceStarted,
            RollNoNursery = sc.RollNoNursery ?? 0,
            RollNoSchool = sc.RollNoSchool ?? 0,
            ServingDays = MealBL.MealServingDays(sc.Id, startDate, startDate.AddDays(6))
        })
    .ToList();
```

This performace improvement does not exclude those suggested by @C.Evenhuis, so for best performance, you should combine them together.